# Allow Only Specific users and superuser to edit a particular field in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model called test.

Test models have three fields - Question, answer, verified.

Superuser - Admin
User1- John
User2- Darren

admin.py file

```
model = Test

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = ['question','answer','verified']
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fields.append('verified')
        return fields
```

This code only allows the superuser to edit the verified record. But what I want is I have to give permission to some of the users to edit this field.

This field should only be visible to admin and john and not to Darren. And Darren will have permission to edit all field in the model except this verified field.

Comment: What condition do you want to add? It should be fairly simple to extend the code above to add a=additional conditions

Comment: This verified field should be visible to some of the specific user while editing the model .

Comment: What users? Are they assigned to a group?

Comment: question edited

Comment: And you don't want to give john superuser? Can you assign john to a "admin" group?

Comment: Yes, I don't want John to assign as superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the line that checks for superuser to add any condition that you like. For instance if you create a group named "admin" this condition will allow users assigned to that group to edit "verified" too

```
    if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='admin').exists():
        fields.append('verified')
```